# Open a box with Bootstrap and Angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am beginning with AngularJS, and I am wondering why there is a conflict between Bootstrap and Angularjs when I try to simply open a box like this:

**Link:**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#open-baggage-box" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="open-baggage-box">Add Now</a>
```

**Box:**

```
    <div id="open-baggage-box" class="collapse add-price-section">
        <div class="open-holder">
            <div class="container">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It actually does not work and I don't really know why. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As angular templates are usually dynamically loaded, bootstrap can look for collapse element before it is rendered.

If you want to use Bootstrap UI elements with AngularJS, I recommend [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) which implements them as Angular directives.

In your case, [collapse directive](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse) will do the job :)

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. What should I use if I prefer not to use bootstrap ui ?

Comment: @maevy I think you don't have that many alternatives then. You can always write your own directive which will imitate that behavior (you can also extract this single directive from bootstrap UI source and use it in your project). It happens very often with Angular that you have to use libraries created directly for Angular if you want everything to run smoothly (especially jQuery-based stuff).